# SQLite C interface: what happens if transaction rollback fails?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, transactions, rollback

I have written a lot of APIs for a project which exploits SQLite with the following approach:

```
sqlite3_exec(mydatabase, "BEGIN;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
/* perform several INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE queries on the database */
if(/* problem detected */){
    sqlite3_exec(mydatabase, "ROLLBACK;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
} else {
    sqlite3_exec(mydatabase, "COMMIT;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

My question is: what happens if the rollback statement fails? I suppose I could check the return value of the commit statement and rollback in case of error, but I do not know what to do if the rollback fails.

Moreover, I have written my code supposing that I can do something like this:

```
sqlite3_exec(mydatabase, "BEGIN;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
/* INSERT data in the database */
/* UPDATE or SELECT records in the database where the record could be a record already stored in the db
or a record inserted with the INSERT statement above */
if(/* problem detected */){
    sqlite3_exec(mydatabase, "ROLLBACK;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
} else {
    sqlite3_exec(mydatabase, "COMMIT;", nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

So basically I assume that if I start a transaction, change something in the db and search for the modified row in the db, that change is immediately visible even if the transaction is still running and the commit has not been issued yet. Is this correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In context of the same connection (i.e. same process and same connection object), all changes to the database made while inside a transaction are visible to subsequent statements in the same transaction.  The entire purpose of a transaction is to accumulate related changes and then to either commit them all at once or reject (i.e. roll back) all the changes together.  If this were not the case, the entire purpose of a transaction would be nullified.

---

If a rollback fails, you should check the [result/error codes](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html) and handle the case accordingly.  Not all fails indicate a critical problem with the database.

A previously committed and/or rolled-back transaction cannot be rolled back again, so it would cause an error.  This would indicate some type of logic/flow error, but not necessarily a problem with the database integrity.  However, if one part of the code attempts a rollback but the transaction was already committed, the data may not be in valid state according to your specific requirements and business logic.  Only you can decide how to handle this type of error.  Fix a bug?  Ignore the error?

An error code of SQLITE_BUSY means that another connection has the database temporarily locked and so it might also prevent a rollback (not certain of this).  A simple delay and re-try could be sufficient to handle this problem.

Other errors could indicate something more serious, like a lost database connection or corrupted journal file, etc.  How you hanlde this is completely dependent on your application and how critical the database is to the application.  Should the error be escalated and terminate the entire program?  Simply logged and ignored?  Perhaps your code could further analyze the connection and/or database files and attempt a recovery?

Comment: Thanks. My database is absolutely essential for my application. Basically I use the database to store metadata about users, groups (of users) and keys of a key management system I am developing using a custom hardware security module. If I loose the database, I loose every information in the KMS except for the keys which are securely stored in the HSM flash memory. The database is only accessed locally by one user at a time so I will never have any concurrency problem (the software to handle the db is single threaded and it does not perform any nested operation on the db).

Comment: Moreover I can say there are no errors in the logic of my application that could cause a rollback of a committed transaction or some similar wrong operation. My main concern is related to sudden application crash, power failure, HSM disconnection from the pc and events like these just before doing commit or rollback of a transaction.

Comment: @matteof93  There is **always** a chance of sudden hardware failure that could leave a database corrupted.  The solution for such problems is not transactions, instead data backups, redundant power supplies, redundant storage, etc... largely irrelevant to discussion of transactions.  You specifically asked about failure during rollback, so the answer stands as is.  sqlite is designed to preserve the integrity of the data when something fails, but I can't tell you how to handle failure of transactoin handling itself.  I posed questions to prompt possible solutions that you could develop.

Comment: @matteof93 You might be interested in reading https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html